# join not returning all elements in left table C# lambda

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 2 tables, the left table has data like this:

[image]

I do a left join with another table with the following expression:

```
 var result = posicion.Join(fact,
                            p => p.Cod_articulo,
                            f => f.Cod_articulo,
                            (p, f) => new { p.Posicion, p.Cant_historico, 
                                            p.Cod_articulo, f.Cantidad_facturada });
```

The problem is that the results don't include some items from the left table as seen below:

[image]

As you can see in the result there is no data for position 3, 6 etc. what would be missing from my join?

Comment: This is not a left join in Lambda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do group join (that is left join in Linq). It's better to do with query syntax:

```
from p in posicion
join f in fact
    on p.Cod_articulo equals f.Cod_articulo into g // GroupJoin
from pf in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { 
   p.Posicion, 
   p.Cant_historico, 
   p.Cod_articulo, 
   Cantidad_facturada = (pf == null) ? null : pf.Cantidad_facturada 
}
```

This query selects all facts corresponding to posicion `p` into group `g`. Then from each group we select results, even if there is no corresponding facts for current posicion (that is `DefaultIfEmpty` case).

Lambda syntax will be much less readable:

```
posicion.GroupJoin(fact,
                   p => p.Cod_articulo,
                   f => f.Cod_articulo,
                  (p, g) => new { p, g })
        .SelectMany(x => x.g.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, pf) => new {
                x.p.Posicion, 
                x.p.Cant_historico, 
                x.p.Cod_articulo, 
                Cantidad_facturada = (pf == null) ? null : pf.Cantidad_facturada 
        });
```

Consider also reading this MSDN article: [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i needed, I agree that is much more readable than using lamdas

Comment: @mmilan I added also lambda syntax, if you need it for some reason (but it's really hard to read and understand)

Answer (score 3):

> what would be missing from my join?

Presumably there are no entries in `fact` which have the corresponding `Cod_articulo` values (e.g. 60155 for posicion 3). `Join` in LINQ represents an inner join, where there has to be an entry in *both* sources in order to create an appropriate result.

If you want a left join, you'd typically use `GroupJoin`, so that each element on the "left" side ends up matching a group of entries from the "right" side, where that group may be empty.